# Mybatis results into Map<Integer, List<Integer>>

Tags: postgresql, mybatis

I have a cyclic query which fetches the result in form of

```
 id | dependencies 
----+--------------
  1 | {1,2,3,4,5}
  2 | {2,3,4,5}
  3 | {3,4,5}
  4 | {4,5}
  5 | {5}
(5 rows)
```

I need to map this data into

```
HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>,
where
column "id" becomes KEY
column "dependencies" becomes VALUE
(dependencies= postgres array obtained after array_agg)
```

Apparantly with, resultSet mapping as

```
@Results(value={

            @Result(column="id", property="key", javaType=Integer.class),
            @Result(column="dependencies", property="value", typeHandler=ArrayTypeHandler.class)
    })


Im getting the results with  return type as
List<Map<Integer, List<Integer>>>, but they are not as expected
```

Is there a way, where I can map the results directly into the map?

Comment: Just returning Map<Integer, List<Integer> in your method the mapping maybe is correct, whats happening? Could you add some more information, as the result you are getting or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You could try ResultHandler:

```
// declared as "final" to be visible in the anonymous class scope
final Map<Integer, String> result = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

ResultHandler resultHandler = new ResultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handleResult(ResultContext resultContext) {
        Map object = (Map) resultContext.getResultObject();
            result.put((Integer)object.get("id"), (String)object.get("dependencies"));
        }
    };

session.select("myStatement", resultHandler);
LOGGER.info(result);
```

You can also do it through mapper interface:

```
// declare in mapper interface
@ResultType(value=Map.class)
@Results(value={
        @Result(column="id", property="id", javaType=Integer.class),
        @Result(column="dependencies", property="dependencies", typeHandler=ArrayTypeHandler.class)
})
void myStatement(ResultHandler resultHandler);

// call
session.getMapper(MyMapper.class).myStatement(resultHandler);
```

You will have to specify the *@ResultType* as Map,
or reference a *@ResultMap("myResultMap")*  whose mapping is defined in the XML and then remove the *@Results*.
Otherwise a BindingException is thrown:

> *Method myStatement needs either a @ResultMap annotation, a @ResultType
>   annotation, or a resultType attribute in XML so a ResultHandler can be
>   used as a parameter.*